# OnActivityResult() method not called in fragment when called fragment from activity

Tags: android, fragment

Hi i have searched regarding "onActivityResult() not called " but after spending number of days   i am not able to call onactivity result.

what i am doing:
 i was calling fragment from activity and then on fragment i was getting images from gallary and it doesn't called onActivityResult of fragment.

Please advice me how to solve this problem.

**Activity class**

```
myswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
if(isChecked)
{

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
CarPoolingSignUpFragment carPoolingSignUpFragment=new CarPoolingSignUpFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.carPoolingLoginFrameLayout,carPoolingSignUpFragment,"SignUp");
fragmentTransaction.commit();

}}
```

**Opening gallary from fragment**

```
ignUpProPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Log.d("daf", "ddddddd");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

try {
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "errrorr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**onActivityResult in fragment**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Log.d("ActivityResult", "---");
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
driverProPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

signUpProPic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(driverProPath));}}
```

Comment: No, it's not called , i have set the log in it to check whether it called or not

Comment: but you are finishing your activity somewhere right? this code is not posted

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `fragment`'s `onActivityResult` inside your `Activity`'s `onActivityResult`. For example:

**Code in my Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: please check mFragment for null before calling fragment's method. i

Comment: Inside Activity, i override the onActivity result and called the corresponding fragment by tag but it doesn't work

Comment: i was doing it as Fragment fragment=getFragmentManager.getFragmentByTag("SignUp"); fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);               super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: put `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` before `fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Comment: Paste what you have done so far as an `Edit` to your question.